# Meaning of $\left| (f\circ f)(x) \right|$ is not differentiable only on single point, when $f(x)$ is a cubic function?

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, cubics

> - $f(x)$ is a cubic function, and its leading coefficient is $1$.
> - $f(x)$ intersects with $x$-axis only on $(1,0)$.
> - $f'(1) \ne 0$.
> - $\left| (f\circ f)(x) \right|$ is not differentiable only on $x=2$.
>
> What is the number of all $f(4)$s, when $f(4) \in \mathbb{Z}$?

**My approach:**

1. $\left| (f\circ f)(x) \right|$ is not differentiable only on $x=2$.
2. It means that the graph of $(f\circ f)(x)$ has to pass $x=2$, but not tangent to $x$-axis.
3. So, the **only number** that satisfies $(f\circ f)(x) = 0$ and $f'(f(x))f'(x) \ne 0$ is $2$.
4. But, since $f(x)=0$ only on $x=1$, step 3 is equivalent to:
5. The **only number** satisfies $f(x)=1$ and $f'(1)f'(x) \ne 0$ is $2$.
6. Applying $f'(1) \ne 0$,
7. $2$ is the only number that satisfies $f(x)=1$ and $f'(x) \ne 0$.

---

8. $f(x) = (x-1)(x^2+px+q)$.
9. $x^2+px+q$ cannot have any roots, so $p^2-4q < 0$.

And I'm stuck here. I have thought about getting $f'(x)$ on step 8, and applying step 7 on it, but I didn't do it because it would give me some meaningless equations which cannot be solved.

Are these steps correct, without any leap of logic?

Comment: I don't agree with point two. What does “pass” here mean, and why would tangency to the $x$-axis have to do with anything?

Comment: @politeproofs I meant "pass" by $f(f(2)) = 0$. I stated about tangent because I thought if absolute function is applied to a certain function, its non-differentiable point only occurs on those "passed points". But if the tangent is 0 on that point, it still can be differentiated.

Comment: Consider the function $f(x) = |x|^3$ for $x \neq 1$. Is $f$ differentiable at $1$?

Comment: @politeproofs Yes it can be differentiated, but in this problem $f(x)$ is just a polynomial, and I can't think of any other cases where it can't be differentiated without passing $x=2$.

Comment: It can? Can you tell me the derivative in that case? Also, it doesn't say that $f$ is a polynomial with domain $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @politeproofs $f'(1) = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{|x|^3-|1|^3}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^3-1}{x-1} = 2$, and I thought composition of cubic functions have a domain $\mathbb{R}$ automatically. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hint : use $f(2)=1$ to express $q$ in terms of $p$. Then use $p^2-4q<0$ to find the possible values of $p$ (note that some values has to be remove from $f'(1)\neq 0, f'(2)\neq 0...$).